# Is the Marseille-London Eurostar service operated by Class 373 or 374 trains?

Tags: trains, london, eurostar, marseille

If both models are used, which one is most common? Specifically, on Thursday departures from Marseille?

Comment: Looking at http://www.eurostar.com/us-en/destinations/route-map suggests that service between London and Marseille requires connecting to a non-Eurostar train.  The "Eurostar direct services" filter indicates that the closest you can get on a Eurostar train is Avignon.

Comment: @phoog Outdated info. A direct service has been introduced, calling at Ashford, Lyon, Avignon and Marseille. Northbound services additionally call at Lille where you alight for border checks

Comment: @phoog Remarkably, the /uk-en/ and /us-en/ website's route maps differ slightly - the UK one has Lyon and Marseilles in yellow (direct) not white (connection), though *both* list Avignon as direct (despite it presumably being on the same line).

Comment: @Andrew Not that remarkable. A line used to operate from London to Avignon-Centre, which had a UK border post. Now, instead, it runs to Marseille, and through Avignon TGV (which has no UK border post) rather than Avignon-Centre

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're operated by [Class 373](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_Class_373) trains: either a refurbished e300 or classic Eurostar. You can check out which train is used by searching for a route on [CaptainTrain.com](https://www.captaintrain.com/). The Marseille train is consistently shown to be the e300:

[image]

I've found a guide on how to get this information from [Seat61.com](http://www.seat61.com/London-to-Paris-by-train.htm#Choosing_your_seat_on_Eurostar):

> In fact, it's now even easier to tell whether you'll get an e320 using www.captaintrain.com.  In the search results, the train number will begin e320 if it's a new e320, or e300 if it is either a refurbished e300 or classic Eurostar.